# How to start Cassandra and Spark services assigning half of the RAM memory on each program?

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, cassandra, jvm-arguments

I have a 4 nodes cluster on which there are installed Spark and Cassandra on each node.
Spark version 3.1.2 and Cassandra v3.11
Let me say that each nodes have 4GB of RAM and I want to run my "spark+cassandra" program all over the cluster.
How can I assign 2GB of RAM for Cassandra execution and 2GB for Spark execution?

**I noted that.**

If my Cassandra cluster is up and I run start-worker.sh command on a worker node to make my spark cluster up, suddenly Cassandra service stops but spark still works. Basically, Spark steals RAM resources to Cassandra. How can I avoid also this?

On Cassandra logs of the crashed node I read the message:

```
 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
```

In fact typing `top -c` and then `shift+M` i can see Spark Service at the top of column Memory

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: 4Gb usually is not enough for Cassandra only, not talking about Spark (except the really toy setups)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spark workers take up the total RAM less 1GB. On a 4GB machine, the worker JVM consumes 3GB of memory. This is the reason the machine runs out of memory.

You'll need to configure the `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` to 1GB to leave enough memory for the operating system. For details, see [Starting a Spark cluster manually](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually).

It's very important to note as Alex Ott already pointed out, a machine with only 4GB of RAM is not going to be able to do much so expect to run into performance issues. Cheers!